# How to cleanly quit a QThread with pending QueuedConnection signals?

Tags: c++, qt5

I have a couple of QObjects. I will call them `DataReceiver` and `DataProcessor` which are encapsulated inside the object `DataHandler`

The `DataReceiver` runs on a QThread. When the QThread is started, the `DataReceiver:run()` is called which loops until told to stop with an `atomic_bool`.

```
DataReceiver::run()
{
    this->stop = false;
    while(!stop)
    {
      //Receive data
      emit data_ready(data);
    }
}
```

The `DataProcessor` is also on its own thread, but only run when a signal is emitted from the `DataReceiver`.

This is what DataHandler.h would look like:

```
class DataHandler
{
    public:
      DataHandler();
      ~DataHandler();

    private:
      QThread data_processing_thread;
      QThread data_receiver_thread;

      DataReceiver data_receiver;
      DataProcessor data_processor;
};
```

I connect these objects with Qt slots/signals and threads in the `DataHandler` constructor like so:

```
DataHandler::DataHandler() {
    connect(&data_receiver_thread, &QThread::started, &data_receiver,
            &DataReceiver::run);

    connect(&data_receiver, &DataReceiver::data_ready, &data_processor,
            &DataProcessor::process);

    data_receiver.moveToThead(&data_receiver_thread);
    data_processor.moveToThread(&data_processor_thread)

    data_receiver_thread.start();
    data_processor_thread.start();
}
```

The problem comes when it is time for these objects to go out of scope. The `DataReceiver` has sent 200 signals for the `DataProcessor` to process, but DataProcessor hasn't been able to process quickly enough and has a large number of signals to process still. Currently, this is how it exits:

```
DataHandler::~DataHandler() {

    data_receiver.stop = true; // Signal the data_receiver to while loop to stop
    data_receiver_thread.quit();
    data_receiver_thread.wait();

    data_processor_thread.quit();
    data_processor_thread.wait();

} //data_receiver and data_processor will go out of scope here
```

So my question is, what happens to the pending signals that weren't processed?
Are they cleared when the `data_processor` or when the `data_processor_thread` object goes out of scope? Is there a better way to cleanly exit? When stopping, I want the remaining pending signals to be canceled so we can stop as fast as possible.

The reason for asking is there isn't much documentation on the memory management and I want to try and avoid memory leaks as much as possible.

Comment: What is `data_receiver_thread`? IMO question lacks important data. This `The DataReceiver runs on its own QThread in a while(!stop) loop` is a strange statement. Maybe you should read: https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong

Comment: I've tried to read that. It simply says to not have objects inherit `QThread`. The `data_receiver_thread` is a QThread. I will add more information to make it clear.

Comment: @MarekR, I've improved the question. Please read again.

Comment: You should post a minimal example, as what you posted seem to be at least an odd usage of QThread.

Comment: I don't understand how this is an "odd usage of QThread". I can give more information, but I don't feel like it would be needed to understand the question.